# why angular in webstorm (TSLINT) send me alert when "_id" in model is definied?

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I doing a MEAN app, but I want to define in my model user "_id" as mongodb/mongoose make it.

I want properties like "*id" transparent as posible, the problem is "*"

tslint variable name must be in lowercamelcase pascalcase or upper_case.

I try to do this:

```
export class MyModel {

    "_id": string;
    etc: etc;
    etc: etc;

}
```

Aparently works, but I wold like some more transparent

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is to fix the TS Lint error, then you could disable it for this specific block. Try the following

```js
/* tslint:disable */
export class MyModel {
  _id: string;
  etc: etc;
  etc: etc;
}
/* tslint:enable */
```

Comment: There is: `_id: string; // tslint:disable-line`